# No logs for a specific custom Sobject

Tags: debug-logs

I use the developer console every day for debug. Today I have a strange behaviour :

On one SObject, when I edit any record in the UI and make (or not) any change, then save it, I get no log in the developer console (but the record is updated).

On any other SObject, doing the same thing does generate a log.

I tried to change the log level to finest for every category, but no success.
The page is a standard Lightning page, nothing special.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

Finally found right after my post...

There was **no automation at all** on this SObject, so nothing happened, except the database update.
No trigger or flow, no validation rule, not even an old workflow... That's quite rare :)

I **enabled** an **apex trigger**, and the **log is now generated**.

I thought the simple update would be logged, but apparently it's not if there's no custom logic.